# Avoid unnecessary load in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I have an `eventReactive` function that loads in two datasets. Each dataset can be chosen, but they both loaded within the same `eventReactive`. However, if the user only changes one of the two datasets, I don't want them both to load but only the one that has changed. I know that this would be much easier with two action buttons but I need to have it in one. Please find example code below.

So in the example, I only want to execute that part of the code again for which the variable has changed. 
ui.r:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for dataset viewer application
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Reactivity"),

  # Sidebar with controls to provide a caption, select a dataset,
  # and specify the number of observations to view. Note that
  # changes made to the caption in the textInput control are
  # updated in the output area immediately as you type
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("caption", "Caption:", "Data Summary"),
      actionButton('Go','Go'),

      selectInput("dataset", "Choose a dataset:", 
                  choices = c("rock", "pressure", "cars")),
      selectInput("dataset2", "Choose a dataset:", 
                  choices = c("rock", "pressure", "cars")),

      numericInput("obs", "Number of observations to view:", 10)
    ),


    # Show the caption, a summary of the dataset and an HTML 
     # table with the requested number of observations
    mainPanel(
      h3(textOutput("caption", container = span)),
      verbatimTextOutput('one'),
      verbatimTextOutput('two'),
      verbatimTextOutput("summary"), 

      verbatimTextOutput("summary2")#, 

      # tableOutput("view"),
      # tableOutput("view2")
    )
  )
))
```

server.r

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)

# Define server logic required to summarize and view the selected
# dataset
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # By declaring datasetInput as a reactive expression we ensure 
  # that:
  #
  #  1) It is only called when the inputs it depends on changes
  #  2) The computation and result are shared by all the callers 
  #   (it only executes a single time)
  #
  datasetInput <- eventReactive(input$Go,{

    ##Only run if input$dataset has changed##
    withProgress(message='Loading 1:This should take very long....',value=0,{
      for(i in 1:5){
        Sys.sleep(1)
        incProgress(i/5)
      }
    x<-switch(input$dataset,
           "rock" = rock,
           "pressure" = pressure,
           "cars" = cars)

    })
###only run if input$dataset2 has changed
    withProgress(message='Loading 2:This should take even longer....',value=0,{
      for(i in 1:5){
        Sys.sleep(1.5)
        incProgress(i/5)
      }       
      y<-switch(input$dataset2,
                         "rock" = rock,
                         "pressure" = pressure,
                         "cars" = cars)
    })




    return(list(x=x,y=y,input1=input$dataset,input2=input$dataset2))
  })

  # The output$caption is computed based on a reactive expression
  # that returns input$caption. When the user changes the
  # "caption" field:
  #
  #  1) This function is automatically called to recompute the 
  #     output 
  #  2) The new caption is pushed back to the browser for 
  #     re-display
  # 
  # Note that because the data-oriented reactive expressions
  # below don't depend on input$caption, those expressions are
  # NOT called when input$caption changes.
  output$caption <- renderText({
    input$caption
  })

  # The output$summary depends on the datasetInput reactive
  # expression, so will be re-executed whenever datasetInput is
  # invalidated
  # (i.e. whenever the input$dataset changes)
  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    dataset <- datasetInput()$x
    summary(dataset)
  })

  output$summary2 <- renderPrint({
    dataset <- datasetInput()$y
    summary(dataset)
  })

  # The output$view depends on both the databaseInput reactive
  # expression and input$obs, so will be re-executed whenever
  # input$dataset or input$obs is changed. 
  output$view <- renderTable({
    head(datasetInput()$x, n = input$obs)
  })
  output$view2 <- renderTable({
    head(datasetInput()$y, n = input$obs)
  })
  output$one<-renderText(datasetInput()$input1)
  output$two<-renderText(datasetInput()$input2)

})
```

I already tried something like this: `if(datasetInput()$input1 != input$dataset){execute...}`
But it doesn't work, probably because you are using a value within a reactive function that is created in the same function...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could separate the two data loading steps into `reactive` expressions on which your `eventReactive` has a dependency. That way when you click Go it calls the two reactive expressions if they have changed input values, but doesn't if the input has not updated. Eg:

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)

ui = fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Reactivity"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("caption", "Caption:", "Data Summary"),
      actionButton('Go','Go'),
      selectInput("dataset", "Choose a dataset:", 
                  choices = c("rock", "pressure", "cars")),
      selectInput("dataset2", "Choose a dataset:", 
                  choices = c("rock", "pressure", "cars")),

      numericInput("obs", "Number of observations to view:", 10)
    ),

    mainPanel(
      h3(textOutput("caption", container = span)),
      verbatimTextOutput('one'),
      verbatimTextOutput('two'),
      verbatimTextOutput("summary"), 
      verbatimTextOutput("summary2")
    )
  )
)

server = function(input, output) {
  dat1 = reactive({
    withProgress(message='Loading 1:This should take very long....',value=0,{
      for(i in 1:5){
        Sys.sleep(1)
        incProgress(i/5)
      }
      switch(input$dataset,
             "rock" = rock,
             "pressure" = pressure,
             "cars" = cars)
    })
  })

  dat2 = reactive({
    withProgress(message='Loading 2:This should take even longer....',value=0,{
      for(i in 1:5){
        Sys.sleep(1.5)
        incProgress(i/5)
      }       
      switch(input$dataset2,
             "rock" = rock,
             "pressure" = pressure,
             "cars" = cars)
    })
  })

  datasetInput <- eventReactive(input$Go,{
    x = dat1()
    y = dat2()
    return(list(x=x,y=y,input1=input$dataset,input2=input$dataset2))
  })

  output$caption <- renderText({
    input$caption
  })

  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    dataset <- datasetInput()$x
    summary(dataset)
  })

  output$summary2 <- renderPrint({
    dataset <- datasetInput()$y
    summary(dataset)
  })

  output$view <- renderTable({
    head(datasetInput()$x, n = input$obs)
  })

  output$view2 <- renderTable({
    head(datasetInput()$y, n = input$obs)
  })

  output$one<-renderText(datasetInput()$input1)

  output$two<-renderText(datasetInput()$input2)
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui,server)
```